# What is the point of the "Archaeologist" and "Excavator" badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, late-answers

According to the tag wiki, a `badge`

> ...[is] awarded to encourage and incentivize positive community actions within the site.

If you've used Stack Overflow for any extensive period of time, you have probably read through the badge list to see which ones you can earn (and possibly try to get them). Chances are, you have come across:

[image]

Before a week ago, I did not really think much of this. But then I passed the `500 reputation` threshold (yay) and could access three review queues, one being **Late Answers**. Late Answers are

> ...a new user's answer to an old question...

New users are not always too concerned about the poor `500` rep users that have to sift through quite a few "late answers". But I wondered whether or not these two badges were driving the surprising amount of "late answers." Getting to my question, I was wondering:

**What is the point of the Archaeologist and Excavator badges because they can *increase the amount of non-useful community actions*, which goes against the point of badges?**

Comment: The idea is that old questions still have value, and may at times need to be improved-  perhaps due to changing technology, perhaps due to changing definitions of a good question.  I'm not so sure about needing a badge for it, but I'm not really a badge type person to begin with.

Comment: Perhaps, but I feel that this draws a lot of bad edits and responses.

Comment: Archaeologist and Excavator are for _edits_, not answers.  They may enlarge the Suggested Edits queue, not Late Answers.  (Arguably the +2 rep for suggested edits is encouragement enough, and the badges should only count non-suggested edits, but the badges may simply predate suggested edits.)  Late Answers is generally kept empty anyway, so I don't see it as a big problem.

Comment: There's probably a Q&A or blog post somewhere announcing the addition of these badges, which may provide rationale for their addition.  I couldn't find anything here on Meta.SO or on the Big Meta, so it's probably in a blog post.

Comment: When you edit a post is says *We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.*. How *absolutely necessary* is a 6 month old posts that has long been forgotten? With posts this old, it is never absolutely necessary... Perhaps you stumble upon 5 eligible examples but never ever a whopping 100.