# Remove the Peer Pressure badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

In my opinion, the Peer Pressure badge encourages bad posts: "Delete own post with a score of -3 or lower". My request is that we remove the peer pressure badge:

- Users should be editing their questions/answers instead of deleting them.
- The badge can lead to more of the same behavior of deleting negative score posts, resulting in question/answer bans.
- Badges are, IMO, meant to encourage positive behavior on Stack Overflow, and unless I'm mistaken, the Peer Pressure badge is the only badge that does not do this.

**EDIT:** The Disciplined badge also falls into the category of not encouraging positive behavior. If your post had a few upvotes, then why would you remove it? A similar post suggested that it could be a wrong answer, but then people wouldn't be upvoting it, and earning the badge would mean that content that is helpful to others is removed.

Comment: The badge is there to help new users discover that keeping the site clean is positive behavior.  You can take something away when you propose a suitable replacement.

Comment: Are you suggesting people do bad posts with the express goal of getting the peer pressure badge?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm just saying that people shouldn't be awarded for doing something wrong.

Comment: I was responding to: *the Peer Pressure badge encourages bad posts*.

Comment: Sure, edit and fix when possible but sometimes it isn't. Sometimes the question turns out to be off topic or simply not well-suited to the site. It's not like users should *never* delete their own posts.

Comment: *"A similar post suggested that it could be a wrong answer, but then people wouldn't be upvoting it"*. I think you might be putting a little too much faith in the voting patterns on SO main.

Comment: _A similar post suggested that it could be a wrong answer, but then people wouldn't be upvoting it_ issues can be found at a later point of time in answers which at first seem to work.. happens in tech/programming. And it would be _good behavior_ to remove such posts which cause problems instead of keeping it around because of positive score

Comment: @Xcoder But deleting a bad post *isn't* doing something wrong.  Deleting a post that's bad is *useful*.  Sure, it would be better if they never posted the bad post in the first place, but people are fallible; even the best of users occasionally make a bad post.  Expecting perfection is unreasonable.  What *is* expected is for people to do their best to correct for their mistakes when they happen, and many times that means deleting the problematic post.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting a comment:

> I'm just saying that people shouldn't be awarded for doing something wrong.

Firstly, the badges do award people doing good things. Secondly, it is pointless to hope that no one will succeed in gaming the system.

On the first point, I will make an anecdote out of my own posts. I have recently got Disciplined in the following manner: I posted a quick answer before thinking of looking for a duplicate. After finding the duplicate, I closed the question against it and deleted my redundant answer, which by then had +4 score. As for Peer Pressure, I don't have it, but I came close once, when I wrote an answer while doing something else. That resulted in a decent explanation accompanied by untested broken code. It got two downvotes before I got rid of it; I'm quite sure it would have gotten a lot more in a higher traffic tag. In both cases I did the right thing, and in the end everyone was happy.

On the second point, one could argue that many other badges can also be won through questionable means. My favourite example is Archaeologist. "Edit 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months." Improving a large number of long-neglected posts -- sounds great, right? Well, it's not so great if the edits consist of adding code formatting as emphasis to a hundred posts. In fact, someone has already made [this very complaint about Archaeologist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315515/2751851). The complaint isn't persuasive, though. If we have gamified incentives, it is unavoidable that at least some people will game the system. In the case of badges, that is a cost of using them to promote good behaviour -- and I have no reason to believe the actual cost is unreasonable in the cases of Peer Pressure, Disciplined or, for that matter, Archaeologist.

Comment: Ah, I've wondered at times what a slew of insipid edits from the same person on old posts is doing in the Review queue, sometimes. <sigh> I am so not badge-oriented... Thanks for reminding me of this one!

Comment: @CindyMeister If we're talking about folks whose insipid edits go to the review queue, rep farming (+2 per edit, up to 500 times) is an alternative, and perhaps more likely, explanation.